# Access Visual Basic Code for concatenating multiple fields (text and numbers together)

Tags: ms-access

I have been set with the task of creating a Microsoft Access database to store customer feedback and to generate a printable report when negative feedback is logged.

On my Feedback form where users can log feedback details, I am trying to develop code to concatenate fields taken from the Feedback table (which the form's record source is set to). What I am aiming to do is develop a unique number which is made up of the following fields from the Feedback table:

- Company name (this is actually a lookup field in the Feedback table which looks up Company Name in the Company table so is therefore a combo-box on the form - appears as a drop down menu on the form)
- Product name
- 2 digits of the week number
- 2 digits of the month
- 2 digits of the year
  (These three date items are extracted from a field called Feedback date in the Feedback table).
- A sequential number starting from 1 which increments so that if another piece of feedback is logged on the same product by the same company this number then changes to 2 and so on.

Basically, the example I'm wanting to replicate is to look like this: 
Company Name_Product Name_0712131

The output of these concatenated fields is meant to be stored in another field in the Feedback table called CF#.

What kind of code should I be writing so that the information I want concatenated gets saved to the database?

Comment: Do they fill out the form, then submit it, then the CF# number is generated?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to add a record (CurrentDB.Execute({SQL code}), ADO commands, DAO commands, DoCmd.OpenQuery), but I suspect you want to know how to create the expression that you are going to add:

```
Dim strCustomerRef As String

'Add the Company Name (assumes the name is in the second column)
strCustomerRef = Me.cboYourComboBox.Column(1)

'Add the Product Name (assumes you have a text box bound to the product)
strCustomerRef = strCustomerRef & "_" & Me.txtTheProductNameTextBox

'Add the date info (assumes you have a text box bound to the date)
strCustomerRef = strCustomerRef & "_" & Format(Me.txtFeedbackDate, "wwmmyy")

'Add the sequence number
strCustomerRef = strCustomerRef & "_" & DCount("CustomerRef", "CF#", "[CustomerRef] Like '" & strCustomerRef & "*'") + 1

'Code to append record here
CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO [CF#] ([CustomerRef], [MoreData]) VALUES ('" & strCustomerRef & "', '" & Me.txtMoreData & "')
```